# Authentication via Spring Boot / Spring Security UserDetailsService results in 302 after successful authentication

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, spring-security

I am following [this tutorial](https://programmingtechie.com/2019/11/08/build-a-full-stack-reddit-clone-with-spring-boot-and-angular-part-3/) to build **REST APIs**. I am trying to build user authentication using Spring Boot and `UserDetailsService`. See the following code:

**ApiUriPaths.java**

```
@UtilityClass
public class ApiUriPaths {

    public static final String ROOT = "/";
    public static final String HEALTH = "/health";
    public static final String AUTH_USER_LOGIN = "/auth/login";
}
```

**WebSecurityConfigurer.java**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfigurer extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;
    
    @Bean(BeanIds.AUTHENTICATION_MANAGER)
    @Override
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
        
        httpSecurity
            .csrf()
                .disable()
            .formLogin()
                .loginProcessingUrl(String.format("%s/**", ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN))
                .usernameParameter("email")
                .passwordParameter("password")
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .logout()
                .logoutUrl(ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGOUT)
                .permitAll()
                .and()
            .sessionManagement()
                .sessionFixation()
                .migrateSession()
            .and()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(ApiUriPaths.HEALTH, ApiUriPaths.User.REGISTER, ApiUriPaths.User.VERIFY).permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

    }
    
    @Autowired
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder authenticationManagerBuilder) throws Exception {
        authenticationManagerBuilder.userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
                .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
        return new BCryptPasswordEncoder();
    }
}
```

**UserController.java**

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN)
    public UserLoginResponseDto login(UserLoginRequestDto userLoginRequestDto) {
        return userService.login(userLoginRequestDto);
    }
}
```

**UserService.java**

```
@Service
@Slf4j
public class UserService implements UserDetailsService {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;
    @Autowired
    private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Override
    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    public UserDetails loadUserByUsername(String email) throws UsernameNotFoundException {
        Optional<UserModel> userModelOptional = userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(email);
        UserModel userModel = userModelOptional.orElseThrow(() -> new UsernameNotFoundException(""));
        User user = new User(userModel.getEmail(), userModel.getPasswordModel().getHash(), !userModel.isDisabled(), !userModel.isExpired(), !userModel.getPasswordModel().isExpired(), !userModel.isLocked(), Collections.singletonList(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("USER")));
        return user;
    }

   public UserLoginResponseDto login(UserLoginRequestDto userLoginRequestDto) {
        Optional<UserModel> userOptional = userRepository.findByEmailIgnoreCase(userLoginRequestDto.getEmail());
        UserModel userModel = userOptional.get();
        UserLoginResponseDto userLoginResponseDto = userModel.toUserLoginResponseDto();
        Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLoginRequestDto.getEmail(), userLoginRequestDto.getPassword()));
        SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(authentication);
        return userLoginResponseDto;
    }
}
```

When I make a login request, Spring calls UserService.loadUserByUsername and authenticates the user successfully but instead of forwarding the request to `LOGIN` endpoint post successful authentication, it returns the following 302 message.

**Request**

```
POST /auth/login HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: PostmanRuntime/7.26.8
Accept: */*
Host: localhost:8080
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Connection: close
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
Content-Length: 41

email=foo%40gmail.com&password=foo
```

**Response**

```
HTTP/1.1 302 
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
Cache-Control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate
Pragma: no-cache
Expires: 0
X-Frame-Options: DENY
Set-Cookie: JSESSIONID=1AC677543095C8DADBAD8DC13944D27E; Path=/; HttpOnly
Location: http://localhost:8080/
Content-Length: 0
Date: Thu, 24 Dec 2020 05:03:24 GMT
Connection: close
```

What is causing the request to result in 302 and not go to `LOGIN` endpoint post successful authentication?

Comment: 404 usually will appear when the request URL not available, please check your url or add here your POST request.

Comment: @Shakthifuture I updated the question with URI file and also postman output. Mind taking a look at it?

Comment: please give a try setting this in your httpSecurityConfiguration -> .loginProcessingUrl(ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN)

Comment: @JuanBC even after changing the URL, the request does not go to authentication controller endpoint but results in 302 redirect to web root.

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is completely normal standard behaviour. You on the other hand need to explain what it is you are trying to implement.

You are saying you are following [this](https://programmingtechie.com/2019/11/08/build-a-full-stack-reddit-clone-with-spring-boot-and-angular-part-3/) tutorial, but your code looks nothing like his:

His security configuration:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity httpSecurity) throws Exception {
    httpSecurity.csrf().disable()
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/api/auth/**")
                .permitAll()
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated();
}
```

He is implementing a custom login page, and using JWT's and not FormLogin. Its a completely different thing. You have done some strange custom FormLogin and you expect it to work the same.

If we go through some of your code:

```
    .formLogin()
            .loginProcessingUrl(String.format("%s/**", ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN))
            .usernameParameter("email")
            .passwordParameter("password")
            .permitAll()
    .and()
```

You are basically saying to Spring:

1. You want to login using a form, that Spring Security will automatically provide for you when you try to access any private endpoint you dont have access to. So you are using the Spring security default built in form and when you go to the root `/` spring will throw an access denied and store this location (because this is where you wanted to go) and then automatically redirect you to `login` where you be served a login form.
2. You type in your username and password, and press LOGIN, it will post your supplied credentials to a custom login endpoint that you have defined here `.loginProcessingUrl(String.format("%s/**", ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN))` for processing the supplied username and password.
3. After a successful processing, you are then `redirected back` to THE ORIGINAL endpoint that you wanted to access in the first place `http:localhost:8080/`.

Spring explains the entire loginflow very good [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form) and the last step states:

> The AuthenticationSuccessHandler is invoked. Typically this is a SimpleUrlAuthenticationSuccessHandler which will redirect to a request saved by ExceptionTranslationFilter when we redirect to the log in page.

Which in plain english means:

When you access something you are not allowed `/` spring security throws an exception, and the filter `ExceptionTranslationFilter` will store the original request of what it was you wanted to access in the first place. And redirect you there when you have authenticated yourself.

You see that in your response:

```sh
HTTP/1.1 302

# You wanted to access http://localhost:8080/
# So thats where you will get redirected after authentication
Location: http://localhost:8080/
```

If you wish to change this default behaviour you can implement a custom `AuthenticationSuccessHandler` that will do something else for you after a successful login.

AuthenticationSuccessHandler.class

```
public interface AuthenticationSuccessHandler {

    /**
     * Called when a user has been successfully authenticated.
     * @param request the request which caused the successful authentication
     * @param response the response
     * @param chain the {@link FilterChain} which can be used to proceed other filters in
     * the chain
     * @param authentication the <tt>Authentication</tt> object which was created during
     * the authentication process.
     * @since 5.2.0
     */
    default void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain chain,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException {
        onAuthenticationSuccess(request, response, authentication);
        chain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    /**
     * Called when a user has been successfully authenticated.
     * @param request the request which caused the successful authentication
     * @param response the response
     * @param authentication the <tt>Authentication</tt> object which was created during
     * the authentication process.
     */
    void onAuthenticationSuccess(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response,
            Authentication authentication) throws IOException, ServletException;

}
```

and then set it:

```
.formLogin()
    .onSuccessHandler(new MyCustomSuccessHandler())
```

So what you are seeing is standard behaviour, but what your intent is is not really clear since you have mish mashed together some kind of strange use-spring-form-login-combined-with-a-custom-processing-page.

My recommendation is that you either follow the tutorial to the letter.

Or you [read the Spring security documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html5/#servlet-authentication-form), and learn the different basic ways of authenticating.

- FormLogin
- Basic Authentication
- default token based login (oauth2)
- token based login with JWT's as tokens (oauth2 + JWT)

Before you start customising stuff.

Answer (score 0):

`@RequestBody` should be added to the inside parameter.

```
@RestController
public class UserController {

    @Autowired
    UserService userService;

    @PostMapping(path = ApiUriPaths.AUTH_USER_LOGIN)
    public UserLoginResponseDto login(@RequestBody UserLoginRequestDto userLoginRequestDto) {
        return userService.login(userLoginRequestDto);
    }
}
```

**Postman** request should be **JSON** request like this.

[image]

**Update**:

In your code, this is line will trigger the `loadUserByUsername` method, do **debug**, and **make sure** the correct email id value is passing.

```
Authentication authentication = authenticationManager.authenticate(new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(userLoginRequestDto.getEmail(), userLoginRequestDto.getPassword()));
```

Comment: Added `@RequestBody` annotation but didn't make any difference. Additionally, when I change the request to type to `json` (from `form`), the `email` parameter in `loadUserByUsername` comes out to be empty string.

Comment: So 404 error resolved, you changed the question to 302?

Comment: 404 was result of postman following 302. Though, as I understand, the API shouldn't return 302 but should continue to the controller endpoint.

Comment: The `email` and `password` are correct. I also debugged this and verified that Spring authenticates correctly. However, once the authentication is successful, the Spring filters try to redirect to `/` instead of continuing the request to `LOGIN` url.

Comment: I didn't understand, rest api won't redirect any URL or API call. Actually, it will return the response.